# Dotnet and sql docker image show error and not show api data

Tags: sql-server, docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

I build a web api in dotnet core using entityframe work. It is runing sucessfully and show data when I run by using IIS. I can also use the swager and postman for CRUD Operations. I also create a sql docker image which is up and runing with sql1 name. However when I try to build docker images of my webapi I see the following error. I didnt manage to find out the core issu. Please help.

```
{"EventId":0,"LogLevel":"Error","Category":"AngularAppApi.Program","Message":"An error occurred while migrating the database.","Exception":"Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server: Could not open a connection to SQL Server)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action\u00601 wrapCloseInAction)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover, SqlAuthenticationMethod authType)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)    at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)    at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection 
owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal\u0026 connection)    at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource\u00601 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal\u0026 connection)    at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource\u00601 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal\u0026 connection)    at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource\u00601 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource\u00601 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at 
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource\u00601 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.\u003C\u003Ec__DisplayClass18_0.\u003CExists\u003Eb__0(DateTime giveUp)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.\u003C\u003Ec__DisplayClass12_0\u00602.\u003CExecute\u003Eb__0(DbContext c, TState s)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func\u00603 operation, Func\u00603 verifySucceeded)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func\u00602 operation, Func\u00602 verifySucceeded)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean retryOnNotExists)    at 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists()    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)   
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.Migrate(DatabaseFacade databaseFacade)    at AngularAppApi.MigrateDatabase.Migrate[T](IHost webHost) in /app/MigrateDatabase.cs:line 22 ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","State":{"Message":"An error occurred while migrating the database.","{OriginalFormat}":"An error occurred while migrating the database."}}
{"EventId":0,"LogLevel":"Error","Category":"AngularAppApi.Program","Message":"An error occurred while migrating the database.","Exception":"Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server: Could not open a connection to SQL Server)    at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal\u0026 connection)    at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource\u00601 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal\u0026 connection)    at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource\u00601 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal\u0026 connection)    at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource\u00601 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource\u00601 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource\u00601 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.\u003C\u003Ec__DisplayClass18_0.\u003CExists\u003Eb__0(DateTime giveUp)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.\u003C\u003Ec__DisplayClass12_0\u00602.\u003CExecute\u003Eb__0(DbContext c, TState s)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func\u00603 operation, Func\u00603 verifySucceeded)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func\u00602 operation, Func\u00602 verifySucceeded)    at 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean retryOnNotExists)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists()    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabaseCreator.EnsureDeleted()    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.EnsureDeleted()    at AngularAppApi.Program.Main(String[] args) in /app/Program.cs:line 23 ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","State":{"Message":"An error occurred while migrating the database.","{OriginalFormat}":"An error occurred while migrating the database."}}
{"EventId":14,"LogLevel":"Information","Category":"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime","Message":"Now listening on: http://[::]:80","State":{"Message":"Now listening on: http://[::]:80","address":"http://[::]:80","{OriginalFormat}":"Now listening on: {address}"}}
{"EventId":0,"LogLevel":"Information","Category":"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime","Message":"Application started. Press Ctrl\u002BC to shut down.","State":{"Message":"Application started. Press Ctrl\u002BC to shut down.","{OriginalFormat}":"Application started. Press 
Ctrl\u002BC to shut down."}}
{"EventId":0,"LogLevel":"Information","Category":"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime","Message":"Hosting environment: Production","State":{"Message":"Hosting environment: Production","envName":"Production","{OriginalFormat}":"Hosting environment: {envName}"}}
{"EventId":0,"LogLevel":"Information","Category":"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime","Message":"Content root path: /app","State":{"Message":"Content root path: /app","contentRoot":"/app","{OriginalFormat}":"Content root path: {contentRoot}"}}
```

As you can see its not able to find the server or database but my sql server image is up a runing.
I am using fowolling commad to build the images.

```
docker run --name dockerwebapi4angular --link sql1:sql1 -e "ServerName=sql1" -e "Database=Projects" -e "UserName=sa" -e "Password=41414141" -p 8181:80 dockersql
```

Can you please help me to find what I did wrong?

my Docker file is this,

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 as build

WORKDIR /app

COPY *csproj .
RUN dotnet restore

COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o pub

#Run phase
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY --from=build /app/pub .

ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet","AngularAppApi.dll" ]
```

Comment: Run the SQL image by publishing the port `-p 9001:1433` try to connect to it and verify it. Check the API code to see if correctly use the ENV variable with SQL setup (logit to console).

Comment: Hi Max, SQL is runing and also ping is sucessfull. I can run migration from my local program, This error appers when I try to make dotnet image and link sql and dont net image connection .

Comment: Ping SQL from your host machine or inside the dotnet machine? The `--link` is [obsolete](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/) try to use a [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) or try with [Networking with standalone containers](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/)